# Apache drill GUI SQuirrel on Windows Class not found

Tags: json, java-8, driver, apache-drill, squirrel-sql

I am trying to use Apache drill GUI on windows 10, I have followed all the instructions on their link https://drill.apache.org/docs/using-jdbc-with-squirrel-on-windows/ , adding the driver shows the message **Driver class org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver successfully registered for driver definition: test** but when creating an alias and testing the connection, it says

```
Drill JDBC Driver alias: JDBC Driver class not found
class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
```

I have also tried adding the **E:\apache-drill-1.16.0\jars\3rdparty** and **E:\apache-drill-1.16.0\jars\classb** folder paths when adding the driver. But in vain, please help me in this regard.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use connection string to connect to Drill instance instead of using a connection string which tries to start Drill in embedded mode: `jdbc:drill:zk=local`. For example, you may start Drill in embedded mode using drill-embedded script or using sqlline, as was described here: https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/ and connect to it using `jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost` connection string.

Regarding the correct error message, squirrelsql handles exceptions in their own way, but it is possible to make changes in Drill to enforce squirrelsql to specify the correct exception. I have created Jira for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-7461

Comment: i have launched drill-embedded.bat, and tried to use drillbit connection string in squirrel, now the error has been changed to below exception java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
 at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
 at oadd.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:83)
 at oadd.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$3.run(SocketUtils.java:80)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at oadd.io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtil

Comment: Sorry, please use `jdbc:drill:drillbit=localhost` connection string, there was a mistake, localhost should be present instead of local. I have updated my comment.

Comment: you are a champ :)